# Предложение с пятью двоеточиями

Tags: пунктуация, орфоэпия, сложное-предложение, двоеточие, редактура

Отвечала на вопрос ребенка, и в Нацкорпусе наткнулась на длинное предложение с пятью двоеточиями (Андрей Белый. Серебряный голубь (1909)):

> Сел он рыбу удить, **хохочет:** червя нацепил — далеко подлетела **уда:** бегут на аер сырой светоловные сети **вод:** бежит золотая змейка, за ней другая, **третья:** промеж них синенькие морщинки, воды бегут, разбиваясь о берега, весело поплескивающей водой; проплывая, крякает сбоку утица; поплавок заплясал, натянулась уда, и бьющаяся рыбешка попадает в пальцы Дарьяльского, где ей разрывается рот, и уже **пломб:** булькнула в ведерцо.

Смутило обилие двоеточий — все ли они нужны?
Стало интересно, а как можно это предложение написать по-другому?

Дополнительно: *аер* — воздух.
Попутно: ***ведерцо*** — куда ставится ударение?

Comment: "Светоловные сети" тоже надо выделить.

Comment: Воды не бегут, разбиваясь о берега, они бегут и в итоге разбиваются о берега. Нет одновременных действий.

Comment: А, с ведерце/ом идея посетила: ведЁрце – ведЁрцЕм, ведерцО – ведерцОм.

Comment: Другой пример  – из МЦ: *Возношу тебя, бремя лучшее, / **Деревцо** моё / Невесомое!* и *Будет наш ответ у входа. / В Рай, под **деревцем** миндальным:/ — Царь! На пиршестве народа. / Голодали — как гидальго!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Смутило обилие двоеточий — все ли они нужны?

Конечно, не все. Большую часть двоеточий в этом отрывке вполне можно было бы заменить на точку с запятой.

Возможно, что двоеточия эти Андреем Белым были поставлены сознательно. Как пишет Валгина в книге «Актуальные проблемы современной русской пунктуации» (2004), раньше «двоеточие обладало гораздо более широким кругом значений, чем в современном русском языке». См., например, у И. Тургенева: *Мы туда-сюда: спрашиваем кухарку: та ничего не знает*.

Но вполне возможно и то, что двоеточия эти оказались вместо точек с запятой  в первом книжном издании «Серебряного голубя» (изд. «Скорпион», 1910) и по ошибке. Вот как там выглядел разбираемый нами фрагмент текста (см. ударение в слове ***ведерцо***):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Похожий сюжет был описан Белым и в другой главе — с другим действующим лицом. Там знаки препинания были использованы во вполне современном значении. См.:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В разбираемом нами отрывке вопросы вызывает не только пунктуация, но и, как минимум, эта его часть: «**бежит** на аер сырой **светоловные сети** вод». Почему-то ошибка с «бежит сети» не была устранена и в «Серебряном голубе», переизданном берлинским издательством «Эпоха» в 1922 году. Осталась прежней и пунктуация:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В изданиях последнего времени несогласованность в  «бежит сети» устранена – теперь «сети бегут». Но насколько такое прочтение соответствовало замыслу автора – не знаю. Может, он предполагал совсем другой вариант: «бежит сеть»?

Стоит ли сейчас менять пунктуацию в этом произведении Андрея Белого – не знаю. Может, оставить как у автора? Но в любом случае не стоит поступать так, как это сделало издательство «Художественная литература», убравшее тире перед словом «пломб» в разбираемом отрывке  (эта версия и воспроизведена в [**Нац. корпусе**](https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=ClgqIQoICAAQChgyIAoQBSAAKMSBm%2FSRvaUOQAVqBDAuOTV4ADICCAE6AQFCLAoqCigKA3JlcRIhCh%2FQodC10Lsg0L7QvSDRgNGL0LHRgyDRg9C00LjRgtGMMAE%3D)): уж к этому-то тире, поставленному в первом книжном издании «Серебряного голубя» в 1910 году, претензий не может быть и сейчас.

---

> Стало интересно, а как можно это предложение написать по-другому?

**Как вариант** (с максимальным сохранением авторских знаков):

> Сел он рыбу удить, хохочет; **(точка с запятой)** червя нацепил —
> далеко подлетела уда; **(точка с запятой)** бегут на аер сырой
> светоловные сети вод; **(точка с запятой)** бежит золотая змейка, за
> ней другая, третья; **(точка с запятой)** промеж них синенькие
> морщинки, воды бегут, разбиваясь о берега, **(так у автора!)** весело
> поплескивающей водой; проплывая, крякает сбоку утица; поплавок
> заплясал, натянулась уда, и бьющаяся рыбешка попадает в пальцы
> Дарьяльского, где ей разрывается рот, и уже — **(тире, как у автора)**
> пломб: булькнула в ведерцо.

Comment: А вы не могли бы записать свой вариант текста, чтобы  ответить на вторую часть вопроса.

Comment: @Слава А как Вы отнесетесь вот к такому оформлению? ***...бежит** на аер сырой **светоловная сеть** вод, бежит золотая змейка, за ней другая, третья; промеж них синенькие морщинки воды бегут, разбиваясь о берега весело поплескивающей водой...*

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова: «_А как Вы отнесетесь вот к такому оформлению?_» === Положительно отнесусь. В ответе написал: _Но насколько такое прочтение соответствовало замыслу автора – не знаю. Может, он предполагал совсем другой вариант: «бежит сеть»?_  Наверное, при переизданиях следовало бы, использовав какой-либо из вариантов, приводить в сносках, как это было у автора? То же и относительно запятой после «разбиваясь о берега» – потому что, где бы ни поставить эту запятую, некоторая корявость этого куска предложения всё равно сохранится.

Comment: Может быть, у нас, теперешних, просто воображения не хватает?

Answer (score 3):

> Попутно: ведерцо — куда ставится ударение?

Туда же, куда в пальтецЕ, деревцЕ, ружьецЕ, письмецЕ, — ведерцО!

Правим Белого:

Сел он рыбу удить — хохочет; червя нацепил — далеко подлетела уда; бегут на аер сырой светоловные сети вод; бежит золотая змейка, за ней другая, третья — промеж них синенькие морщинки; воды бегут, разбиваясь о берега (УБРАТЬ ЗПТ!) весело поплескивающей водой; проплывая, крякает сбоку утица; поплавок заплясал, натянулась уда, и бьющаяся рыбешка попадает в пальцы Дарьяльского, где ей разрывается рот, и уже — пломб! — булькнула в ведерцо.

---

Нашла туманно-невнятное:

> промеж них синенькие морщинки; воды бегут, разбиваясь о берега весело
> поплескивающей водой

Возможно,

*промеж них синенькие морщинки водЫ — бегут, разбиваясь о берега весело поплескивающей водой,*

*промеж них синенькие морщинки; вОды бегут, разбиваясь о берега весело поплескивающей водой,*

однако:

***морщинки воды, разбиваясь водой***

или

***вОды бегут, разбиваясь водой***, —

о нет, это халтура, о дайте мне атмосфЭры... О_о

---

Итак, по законам редактуры невнятицу согласуем с автором; при отсутствии такового — с душеприказчиком, наследником; при отсутствии оных

ставим в тексте звёздочку по истечении невнятицы, за последним ёйным словом,

и — изображаем сноску:

***Sic! Так у автора.***

---

Варьянт: *...промеж них синенькие морщинки воды бегут, разбиваясь о берега; весело поплескивАЯ водой, проплывая, крякает сбоку утица*?! —

но нет же, возвращаемся к

***Sic! Так у автора.***

---

---

Нашла текст в Инете:

> Подлинно - **именинник:** с само**ш**о с утра, как т**р**лько он
> разгулялся после ночи, заходило сердце его, загудело, и не знает, что
> ему с радостью **делать:** ухватиться ли за стамеску, намаракать ли
> какой, черт подери, вирш, на пруд ли идти уди**р**ь **рыбу?С ел** он рыбу
> удить, **хохочет:** червя нацепил - далеко подлетела **уда:** бегут на
> аер сырой светоловные сети **вод:** бежит золотая змейка, за ней
> другая, **третья:** промеж них синенькие морщинки, воды бегут,
> разбиваясь о берега, весело поплескивающей водой; проплывая, крякает
> сбоку утица; поплавок заплясал, натянулась уда, и бьющаяся рыбешка
> попадает в пальцы Дарьяльского, где ей разрывается рот, и уже **пломб:**
> булькнула в ведерцо.

Зримое доказательство халтурных переизданий:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Да, г-н Бугаев, это не литература...

---

---

[«Сере́бряный го́лубь» — первый роман Андрея Белого, один из ярчайших образцов прозы русского символизма.](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%8C)

> Повествование в просторечной сказовой манере не без иронии ведёт
> автор, «обряженный в маску Гоголя-проповедника». Его напевная речь
> насыщена инверсией, повторами, звукописью, «фольклорными речениями,
> диалектной лексикой, порой избыточно цветистой». Внутреннее состояние
> главного героя объективируется в «лиризованных пейзажах» наподобие
> «вереницы трехсложников в зачине второй главы романа»...

Comment: Пы.Сы. Двойной скобки нет в природе:  (Андрей Белый. Серебряный голубь (1909).

Comment: вОды бегут: разбиваясь о берега, весело поплескивающей водой - он так хотел, но решил, что будет лишнее двоеточие.

Comment: Всё равно сохраняется 

*вОды бегут, разбиваясь водой*.

Comment: Ну да, но не обязательно, он может волны хотел написать, но подумал какие на реке волны, будут воды. Воды бегут разбиваясь о берега, воды бегут весело поплескивающей водой.

Comment: Я доредактировала ответ - см.

Comment: Сообщение на Ваше "Пы.Сы". Конечно же, двойные скобки *есть* в природе. Есть они и в публикации Института русского языка им. В. В. Виноградова Российской академии наук: *...3) существительные с уменьш. суф., образованные от родовых наименований (Красное Озерко (озеро)); 4) существительные, называющие титулы, звания, профессии, должности и под. (Адмирала Кузнецова (хребет)), 5) прилагательные (Верхняя Тунгуска (река))...* (https://orfo.ruslang.ru/rules/rule/4)

Comment: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5+%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8#:~:text=%D0%92%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%85%20%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D0%BE,.%2C%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%2C%20%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C).

Comment: Галина, так я Вам и процитировала то, на что ссылается "Грамота". *Есть* двойные скобки в природе, а запретов на их использование — нет. "Как правило" — это не запрещение.

Comment: Римуля, я стокамнога букв ниасиливаю, я из практики исхожу. НЕВЕРМОРРР!

Answer (score 1):

```
Смутило обилие двоеточий — все ли они нужны?
```

Я думаю, что двоеточие у Белого использовано в особом смысле — это **разделители текста.** Но я  вместо двоеточия поставила бы **точку.** Тогда авторское деление будет **сохранено**, и это правильно.

*Сел он рыбу удить, хохочет. Червя нацепил — далеко подлетела уда. Бегут на аер сырой светоловные сети вод.  Бежит золотая змейка, за ней другая, третья. Промеж них синенькие морщинки, воды бегут, разбиваясь о берега, весело поплескивающей водой; проплывая, крякает сбоку утица; поплавок заплясал, натянулась уда, и бьющаяся рыбешка попадает в пальцы Дарьяльского, где ей разрывается рот, и уже пломб. Булькнула в ведерцо.*

Comment: Может быть, может быть... Вот только последнее двоеточие, мне кажется, в такой "расклад" не вписывается. "Пломб" — это очень похоже на "плюх" или "бултых".

Comment: У  этого автора все возможно: он так видит))  Поэтому текст лучше не трогать. И я его так лучше вижу (с расставленными точками).  Но текст интересный:  он же характеризует главных героев, их внутренний мир, новые впечатления от жизни.  Я люблю сравнивать литературу и живопись, они для меня всегда рядом.  Трудно представить, что мы возьмем кисть и будем править известного художника. Скорее, можно написать новую картину  для того же содержания. Вот это интересный вариант для обсуждения...